# Numpy In place transpose

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy ndarray shaped (H, W, 3)

I need to do this

`new_arr = arr[:, :, [2,1,0]]`

I timed it and it takes a few ms. And my understanding is that this is a copy. Is there an place operation that is faster?

Comment: Try `arr1=arr[:,:,::-1]`.  Not in place, but it is a view.

Comment: That's not transpose.  `np.flip(arr, 2)` does what I suggested - reversing the order of elements along one axis.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a library for performing in-place transpositions for 2d, 3d, and 4d arrays. In place transposition is faster than numpy for square matrices. Otherwise, it is more memory efficient, but slower.

https://github.com/seung-lab/fastremap